Mudblazor MudSelect not displaying values in MudSelectItem
MudSelect doesn't open and I can't select any values.
Visual Studio 17.10.3 /
.Net Core 8 /
MudBlazor v7.1.1 (I was on 6.19.1 but upgraded due to this issue)
Here's how to repeat this.

Install the Visual Studio mudblazor template


dotnet new install MudBlazor.Templates


Create a new Mudblazor project using .Net 8

Paste this code into the Home.razor page


@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@code
{
    public int SelectedDay { get; set; } = 1;
}

<h1>SelectedDay = @SelectedDay</h1>
<hr />
 <MudSelect T="int" @bind-Value="SelectedDay" Label="Days"
            RenderMode="MudBlazor.RenderMode.Synchronous"> 
    @for(var i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@i" />
    }
</MudSelect>


The resulting drop down is visible but doesn't work.  No drop down list.  It only shows the default value bound to the SelectedDay property.



Isn't the home page of the template statically rendered? (depending on what template you selected of course).... The select requires an interactive render mode

I updated the code above to use Synchronous RenderMode.  There was no change.  The drop down still does not show up.  I don't know why the home page wouldn't work but I copied it to a test.razor page and it didn't work there either.

Honestly, looking at your screenshot I'm skeptical about whether or not MudBlazor is actually correctly installed in your application (but you said you used to template so it should be). The page doesn't appear to be styled with Mud css. Unless you've overwrote some thing like font for instance, you rendered content should look like https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEQyOhQzpswdjmOT .

you were right about the rendermode...  but I had to create a new project and select render mode: global in order to get the combo box to work.

I was getting this error:

warn:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Duplicate MudPopoverProvider detected. Please ensure there is only one provider,
or disable this warning with PopoverOptions.ThrowOnDuplicateProvider.

But in my search I could only find one  which was in my MainLayout.razor file.  But, I removed it and now it works.
This website was also helpful in checking possible issues with this:
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/8051

The next problem was in my app.razor file.  Make sure to change these settings to make your project globally interactive.
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

... or you can create a new MudBlazor project from the template and select render mode: global and that will set these attributes automagically
